# laravel migration rename column then add another column after it

Tags: php, laravel, migration

I am trying to rename a column using Laravel migration:

```
$table->renameColumn('name', 'firstname');
```

Also, I want to add another column after the `firstname` has been added:

```
$table->renameColumn('name', 'firstname');
$table->string('middlename', 255)->after('firstname')->nullable();
```

But I am getting an error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'firstname' in <TABLE_NAME> (SQL: alter table <TABLE_NAME> add `middlename` varchar(255) null after `firstname`)
```

How can I *wait* for the `firstname` column to be added before I add another column after it?

Comment: add the column before you rename the column, and add it after 'name'.

Comment: Ohh yeah sorry I didn't think of that. My bad :D

Comment: no problem, glad I could help :-)

Comment: Or, make that two migrations

Comment: You should add your new column to another migration and call it after renaming.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `Schema` two times in a single migration file may solve the issue.

First:

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->renameColumn('name', 'firstname');
});
```

Second:

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('middlename', 255)->after('firstname')->nullable();
});
```

Sample Migration:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->renameColumn('name', 'firstname');
});

Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('middlename', 255)->after('firstname')->nullable();
});
```

Comment: I didn't know that was possible. Thanks man!

Comment: You're welcome @Yamakenji, I wish it solves your problem.